# How does $wpdb handle COUNT(*)

Tags: database, wpdb

I understand how to do simple queries and display results using $wpdb. This is my process:

```
<?php $sql = 'select * from wp_votes;'; ?>
<?php $votes = $wpdb->get_results($sql); ?>
<?php if ( !empty ( $votes ) ) { ?>
     <?php foreach ( $votes as $vote ) { ?> 
          <td><?php echo $vote->id; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $vote->post_id; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $vote->date_voted; ?></td>
     <?php } ?> 
<?php } ?>
```

Now, what if my query is more complicated, where there is a COUNT(*) involved, like so:

```
<?php $sql = 'select wp_votes.post_id, wp_posts.post_title, count(*) from wp_votes INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_votes.post_id = wp_posts.id group by wp_votes.post_id order by count(*) desc;'; ?>
```

This should return:

```
--------+------------+----------+
Post ID | Post Title | Count(*) |
--------+------------+----------+
1       |  "My post" |   6
2       |  "Hello..."|   5
```

Would it be OK if I do something like this?

```
<?php $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_N); ?>
```

and then, to get the count,

```
<?php echo $row[2]; ?>
```

EDIT: Turns out, it's actually just this simple, I don't have to do anything else $row[x] will work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to ask. By `OK` do you mean `Can my query be improved?` or `Will this query work?`

Comment: Will this query work?

Comment: Nevermind, so it does work.

Answer (score 8):

You can just use `echo $wpdb->get_var( $sql )`:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/